# ipython: SMILES parse error

Tags: ipython

In shell:

```
balloon/balloon -f balloon/MMFF94.mff --nconfs 1 --nGenerations 300 "[H]OC(=O)C([H])([H])[C@@]1([H])C2=C([H])C([H])=C(OC([H])([H])C([H])([H])C([H])([H])OC3=C(OC([H])([H])[H])C([H])=C(C([H])=C3[H])C3=NC(OC([H])([H])C([H])([H])[H])=C(S3)C([H])([H])[H])C([H])=C2C([H])([H])C1([H])[H]" AAA.pdb
```

It works very well. However, when I try to implement use ipython, there is an error, my code as follows:

```
import os
str3="[H]OC(=O)C([H])([H])[C@@]1([H])C2=C([H])C([H])=C(OC([H])([H])C([H]([H])C([H([H])OC3=C(OC([H])([H])[H])C([H])=C(C([H])=C3[H])C3=NC(OC([H])([H])C([H])([H][H])=C(S3)C([H])([H])[H])C([H])=C2C([H])([H])C1([H])[H]"

str4="balloon/balloon -f balloon/MMFF94.mff --nconfs 1 --nGenerations 300  str3 AAC.pdb"

#os.system('balloon_options')
os.system(str4)
```

The error is:

> Cannot parse input str3 SMILES parser said: Syntax error after s
>   Skipping.

What is wrong with the problem?

By the way, balloon is the software which can put SMILES STRING into mol2 or pdb format.(SMILES STRING is like [H]OC(=O)C([H])([H])[C@@]1([H])C2=C([H])C([H])=C(OC([H])([H])C(HC([H([H])OC3=C(OC([H])([H])[H])C([H])=C(C([H])=C3[H])C3=NC(OC([H])([H])C([H])([H][H])=C(S3)C([H])([H])[H])C([H])=C2C([H])([H])C1([H])[H])

Answer (score 2):

You want to give the contents of the string `str3` as an argument to `balloon/balloon`, but instead you're giving the string `"str3"` as the argument, and the string `"str3"` isn't valid SMILES.

Try using this line:

```
str4="balloon/balloon -f balloon/MMFF94.mff --nconfs 1 --nGenerations 300 " + str3 + " AAC.pdb"
```